# Sublime text: Home key not moving to the beginning of line

Tags: sublimetext3

I do the following in sublime text:

```
Ctrl + A (select all)
Ctrl + Shift + L (into column selection)
Home
```

i want all the cursors to go to the starting of each line. But in some lines the cursor not going to the beginning of the line

[image]

The below is how home key is defined in the Default

```
{ "keys": ["home"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "bol", "extend": false} },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the key bindings that use the <kbd>Home</kbd> key to jump the cursor to the start of the line use the `move_to` command to move the cursor position and specify in the `to` argument the value of `"bol"`. This includes not just the "bare" key, but also the shifted version that extends the selection, and so on.

The `"bol"` value of `to` tells `move_to` to move the cursor to the beginning of the line, but it toggles between two different beginning of line "states":

1. The location where the line text starts (for indented lines), which is the "soft" beginning of the line.
2. Column 1, which is the "hard" beginning of the line

Depending on where the cursor currently sits, you get one or the other, but pressing the key a second time flips the position to the other state.

For example, given a Python example like the following, where `|` is where a cursor is sitting:

```py
def somefunc():|
    print("Hello")|
```

The first time you press <kbd>Home</kbd>, the cursor will jump to the `p` in print, because that's the "soft" beginning of the line. While the cursor is there, if you press <kbd>Home</kbd> again the cursor will jump to the "hard" beginning of the line. Pressing <kbd>Home</kbd> again will put the cursor back on the `p`. For the `def` line, the cursor will jump to the first column when you press the key and stay there, because it's not indented at all.

The general idea is that in most cases when you want to jump to the start of the line, it's because you want to make edits to the text that starts there without taking the indent into account (in the above example, say you wanted to swap `print` for `log`, it's handier if when you press <kbd>Home</kbd> you don't have to arrow right a bunch to get back to the function).

In your particular case you can see this happening when you press the key; the lines containing just indent white space jump to the start, as do the lines that physically start in column 1. All of the other lines jump to the `soft bol` instead.

If you work in files or content where blank lines don't have any trailing white space and are truly "blank", then you could do what you want to do by pressing <kbd>Home</kbd> a second time. In that case all of the lines currently sitting at the `soft bol` would jump to the `hard bol`, and any lines already at the `hard bol` will stay there (because the line is empty).

In your case that won't work because all of the blank lines contain spaces, so pressing the key will swap those lines to the `soft bol` while the other ones go to the `hard bol` instead, and you end up with a weird flip-flip that never gets you where you want to be.

One way to fix this would be to use the `trim_trailing_white_space` command to remove all trailing white space from lines first, in which case you could press <kbd>Home</kbd> twice.

This command is the one that gets executed when you save a file and have `trim_trailing_white_space_on_save` turned on in your preferences, but it's not bound to any keys or menu items by default. So to do that you would first have to bind it to a key, add it to the command palette, turn on the setting and save the content first, etc.

Alternatively you can bind an alternate key (or re-bind the <kbd>Home</kbd> key) in your user bindings to specify a `to` of `hardbol` instead, which will make that key always jump to column 1 no matter what:

```json
{ 
    "keys": ["home"], 
    "command": "move_to", 
    "args": {"to": "hardbol", "extend": false},
}
```

Comment: Great answer! In that code blurb at the bottom you have an extra closing curly-brace on the "args" line.

Comment: @SeanColombo whoops. fixed :)